# QLineEdit: disable a part of text with or without mask

Tags: python, qt4, mask, qlineedit

I would like to insert a mask in a qLineEdit widget, where at the left side the user can insert any text he wants (limited to the maximum limit of qLineEdit) and at the right there whould be a disabled text (mask).

Unfortunatelly I am not abled to upload a picture with the wanted result. 
An example could be that the qLineEdit will accept lenght values in meters. The qLineEdit should have an disabled 'm' at the very right of the widget and at the left part the lenght can be inserted manually by the user.

f.e. [1234.567   **m**], where **m** is **disabled**

I am working with Python 2.7 and pyqt4.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy enough using [`QLineEdit::setInputMask()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop), provided you don't have any special requirements regarding the behaviour of the input while using the mask; I found it hard to customize when it was set. Example:

```
input.setInputMask("0009.000 m")
```

As an alternative [you can set](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qlineedit.html#setValidator) a [`QDoubleValidator`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qdoublevalidator.html) for the edit widget and add the units as separate label to the window layout right beside it.